# Edit Text in Pop Up Box

Tags: ios, iphone

I need some kind of easy way to be able to edit a title when a button is pressed. I would basically just redirect to a view controller with the edit possibility included but that just seems to "heavy". It would be far better to just be able to edit text in a pop up box or something. Is this possible and if so how would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an UIAlertview control to update your title.
In your button click put the following code.For example

```
   -(IBAction)ButtonClick:(id)sender{
       UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Message"   delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Done" otherButtonTitles:nil];
       alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
       [alert show];
       [alert release];
     }
```

In the UIAlertViewDelegate method

```
    -(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
        if(buttonIndex == alertView.cancelButtonIndex)
            NSLog(@"%@", [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text);
     }
```

I hope this will help you.
**Please note the alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput only works in iOS 5.0 and later.**